# Activate passcode lock after 30 mins of inactivity?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, cydia

I have a jailbroken iPhone 4S. The current time options for a passcode lock are:

- Immediately
- After 1, 5, or 15 minutes
- After 1 or 4 hours

However I would prefer using 30 mins or 45 mins, something in between. Is there a Cydia app that allows me to modify this?

*EDIT*

Still cannot find a feature, anyone knows any possible solution ?

Comment: Did you find anything out here?

Comment: Still waiting ... I really want such feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jailbreak tweak called PassTime which lets you set custom time option for activating passcode lock.

[image]

PassTime is available for **$0.99** under the BigBoss repo on Cydia.